# Javascript-Applet communication: how to pass return values back to Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, json, applet, json-rpc

I have some javascript code that needs to call a method in an applet.  The applet and the javascript are running in the same webpage. I know how to call applet methods from javascript and vice versa (e.g., using `MyAppletID.appletMethodName(args)` and `JSObject`, respectively), but both of these techniques only allow one-way communication.  They don't permit return values to be passed from one language back to the other.

I'd like to be able to do something like this...

```
var result = 0;
callAppletMethod( JSON.stringify(args), function(r) { result = r; } )
```

... to call an applet method and store the return value in `result`.

Can anyone suggest a technique, library or toolkit that implements this sort of two-way Javascript-Applet communication?

Should I consider using a remote procedure call protocol like [JSON-RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON-RPC)? Or is there a better approach?

(I'm new to javascript and web programming.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var result = MyAppletID.appletMethodName(args)
```

... should work fine to get a result from Java out to JavaScript.